# Use Of External JavaScript file in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

External JavaScript file is not working inside angular 2 component. It's showing error `myEObject is not defined`.

### external.component.html

```
<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
<button type="button" (click)="callFun()">Try it</button>
```

### external.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../myExternal.js';

declare var myEObject: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'external-file',
    templateUrl: './external.component.htmll'
})
export class ExternalComponent {

    callFun(){
        myEObject.myFunction();
    }
}
```

### myExternal.js

```
var myEObject = (function() {

    return {
        func1: function() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
        }
    } 

})(myEObject||{})
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: You should export your function before import

Comment: It's showing same error (myEObject is not defined)

Comment: if you need a ugly fast way for Singleton - use window.myEObject = myEObject and then use  it. I do now rite it as an answer becase it ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Execute this command through terminal ---

   ```
   npm install jquery --save,

   npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
   ```
2. move  myExternal.js file to assets folder

Comment: ya worked for me .Thank you very much.. But is it mandatory to keep myExternal.js file inside assetes folder ?